# C++ Specify Headers Include Directory in Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, directory, pragma

Is there a way to specify include directories in the code, perhaps via a #pragma?

I have my project setup as "src/" and "include/" folders. I am trying to compile in Visual Studio 2010, but I don't want to set it up in the project settings.

Is there another way to allow it to compile instead of having to specify the include as

```
#include ../include/ss.h
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the project settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Correct(tm) way to specify search directories is with compiler flags. In Visual Studio you do this by playing with the project settings, or its compiler's `/I` commandline parameter.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I didn't have access to a Visual C++ compiler. :-S

Answer (score 0):

In Visual studio, you can also define include folders by setting them via Options/File Locations. Then you don't need to repeat them in every project setting. (Assuming that's what you're after). It is a bit weird to define absolute paths in source code, you'll never know from which folder/drive a build is run.